# IE8 CSS Selector pure CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I get a little giddy when I come across perfect uses for :nth-child or :nth-of-type (read about the difference). The better you understand them, the more css nerdgasms you get to have!

Does any body knows how with pure css to supoort IE8 for this rule

```
li:nth-child(n+2) {
    color: green;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `IE8` that rule can be replaced with

```
li + li  {
    color: green;   
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqMwrW

Comment: I want all atfer first

Comment: can you explain better your comment above? In the example all elements are green after the first one.